# How does *ngFor work in Angular when data is appended to existing array?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have an array say, `dataArray`, which has 100 items. I am using ngFor to show 100 checkboxes initially. There is a button to load next 100 items. On click of this button, I would append 100 more items to `dataArray`, with this `dataArray` shall have 200 items. My question is, does Angular run the ngFor loop again to build 2nd set of items (including 1st 100 items too) or is it smart enough to loop only the 2nd set of items (only 100) and append them to the existing DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you append the items, the whole for loop must be re - run.

The way to avoid this is to provide a `trackBy` function. The `trackBy` function tells angular that the items are changed only when the specified attribute(such as an id) is changed. This allows angular to only change DOM nodes whose specified attribute has changed.

For more info:

[Angular 2 track by explanation](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted. Cheers!